# Pulling the ID of a single Subnet created using For Each

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am still working on my Hub Spoke setup for AKS using Terraform. I have made some progress and I am able to get my subnets and Vnets set up, however I am trying to deploy a VM in my VM Subnet. The issue I run into is, the VM requires a Network Interface. One of the variables needed is the Subnet ID of the VM Subnet. Because I used the for each statement to create multiple subnets, I am struggling to pull the id of the specific subnet I need.

I know I can create a NIC for each subnet, but when I go to setup the VM I will run into the same issue where I need to find out how to use the designated NIC.

My code is as follows:

```
terraform {

  required_providers {
    azapi = {
      source  = "azure/azapi"
      version = "= 1.7.0"
    }

    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "= 3.16.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_subscription" "current" {}

locals {
  spoke_subnets = {
    "aks-spoke" = {
      address_space = ["10.11.0.0/16"]
      name = "aks-spoke"
    }
    "vm-spoke" = {
      address_space = ["10.12.0.0/16"]
      name = "vm-spoke"
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "test" {
  name     = "ty-rg"
  location = "westeurope"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "hub" {
  name                = "hub"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.test.location
  address_space       = ["10.10.0.0/16"]

  subnet {
    name           = "GatewaySubnet"
    address_prefix = "10.10.0.0/24"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "spokes" {
  for_each            = local.spoke_subnets
  name                = each.key
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.test.location
  address_space       = each.value.address_space
}

#Subnet for VMs - Not sure if correct
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnets" {
    for_each             = local.spoke_subnets
    name                 = each.key
    resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
    virtual_network_name = each.value.name
    address_prefixes     = each.value.address_space
}


resource "azapi_resource" "network_manager" {
  type      = "Microsoft.Network/networkManagers@2022-07-01"
  name      = "networkmanager"
  parent_id = azurerm_resource_group.test.id
  location  = azurerm_resource_group.test.location

  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      networkManagerScopeAccesses = [
        "Connectivity",
        "SecurityAdmin"
      ]
      networkManagerScopes = {
        subscriptions = [
          data.azurerm_subscription.current.id
        ]
      }
    }
  })
}

resource "azapi_resource" "spoke_group" {
  type      = "Microsoft.Network/networkManagers/networkGroups@2022-07-01"
  name      = "spokes"
  parent_id = azapi_resource.network_manager.id

  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      description = "VirtualNetwork"
    }
  })
}

resource "azapi_resource" "spoke_group_members" {
  type      = "Microsoft.Network/networkManagers/networkGroups/staticMembers@2022-07-01"
  for_each  = azurerm_virtual_network.spokes
  name      = each.value.name
  parent_id = azapi_resource.spoke_group.id

  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      resourceId = each.value.id
    }
  })
}

resource "azapi_resource" "hub_spoke_configuration" {
  type      = "Microsoft.Network/networkManagers/connectivityConfigurations@2022-07-01"
  name      = "hub-spoke"
  parent_id = azapi_resource.network_manager.id

  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      appliesToGroups = [
        {
          groupConnectivity = "None"
          isGlobal          = "False"
          networkGroupId    = azapi_resource.spoke_group.id
          useHubGateway     = "True"
        }
      ]

      connectivityTopology  = "HubAndSpoke"
      deleteExistingPeering = "True"
      hubs = [
        {
          resourceId   = azurerm_virtual_network.hub.id
          resourceType = "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks"
        }
      ]
      isGlobal = "False"
    }
  })
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "vm-nic" {
    name                 = "ty-vm-nic"
    location             = azurerm_resource_group.test.location
    resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
    enable_ip_forwarding = true

    ip_configuration {
    name                          = "ty-vm-ip"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.subnets["vm-subnet"].id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    }
}
#Virtual Machine for testing Hub-Spoke topology
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "test-vm" {
    name                  = "ty-test-vm"
    location              = "westeurope"
    resource_group_name   = "ty-rg"
    network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.vm-nic.id]
    vm_size               = var.vmsize

    storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "16.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
    }

    storage_os_disk {
    name              = "myosdisk1"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
    }

    os_profile {
    computer_name  = "ty-vm"
    admin_username = var.username
    admin_password = var.password
    }

    os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = false
    }

    tags = {
    environment = "hub-spoke"
    }
}

resource "null_resource" "network_manager_commit" {
  depends_on = [
    azapi_resource.hub_spoke_configuration
  ]

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<CMD
            AccessToken=$(az account get-access-token --query accessToken --output tsv) && \
            curl -X POST https://management.azure.com${data.azurerm_subscription.current.id}/resourceGroups/${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkManagers/${azapi_resource.network_manager.name}/commit?api-version=2021-02-01-preview \
            -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
            -H "Authorization: Bearer $AccessToken" \
            -d '{"targetLocations": [ "${azurerm_resource_group.test.location}" ], "configurationIds": [ "${azapi_resource.hub_spoke_configuration.id}" ], "commitType": "Connectivity"}' \
            -v
        CMD
  }
}
```

My issue is with the following line:
`subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.subnets["vm-subnet"].id`

I have tried various versions of declaring the specific subnet I want to create the NIC for. When I attempt to state the specific resource: `subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.subnets.vm-subnet.id`

I get the following error:
│ Because azurerm_subnet.subnets has "for_each" set, its attributes must be accessed on specific instances.
│
│ For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
│     azurerm_subnet.subnets[each.key]

I have also tried the each.key variable but can't seem to get it working correctly. I know it is probably something i have overlooked but I desperately need help with this.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have subnet called `vm-subnet`. The only valid values are `aks-spoke` and `vm-spoke` based on your `local.spoke_subnets`. Guess that you wanted `vm-spoke` instead of `vm-subnet`:

```
subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.subnets["vm-spoke"].id
```

Comment: @CodeRookie How did it go? Is it still unclear why do you get the error?